# Diazo theme with json attributes error: "Attribute 'data-plugin-options': Failed to compile the expression"

Tags: json, attributes, plone, theming, diazo

I have a static theme that contains some json attributes for customizing jquery plugins, like

```
data-plugin-options='{"directionNav":false, "animation":"slide", "slideshow": false, "maxVisibleItems": 6}'
```

diazo compiler complains about this like

```
Invalid expression [0:0]
compilation error, element 'div' [400:0]
Attribute 'data-plugin-options': Failed to compile the expression ''directionNav':false, 'animation':'slide', 'slideshow': false, 'maxVisibleItems': 6' in the AVT. [0:0]
Invalid expression [0:0]
compilation error, element 'div' [445:0]
Attribute 'data-plugin-options': Failed to compile the expression ''directionNav':false, 'animation':'slide'' in the AVT. [0:0]
Invalid expression [0:0]
compilation error, element 'div' [512:0]
Attribute 'data-plugin-options': Failed to compile the expression ''controlNav':false, 'slideshow': false, 'animationLoop': true, 'animation':'slide'' in the AVT. [0:0]
```

and breaks the rendering.

Is there a way for making this work (beside moving the conf to js)?

Comment: Can we see a larger snippet of the static theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only solution - and that actually make sense - is to split the parameters in more than one `data` attribute. Like:

```
data-plugin-directionNav="false"
data-plugin-animation="slide"
data-plugin-slideshow="false"
data-plugin-maxVisibleItems="6"
```

Answer (score 0):

These are TALES expressions. Try starting with 'string:'. You'll need to escape '$' and ';' if you use them.

Check the [plone.app.theming](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming/1.1.1) page on PyPI; search for "The right hand side is a TALES expression" for the documentation section covering this.

Comment: I tried this but nothing changed. Same error. I think is meant to work only on theme's parameters but I need that into the static html itself.

Comment: I was indeed thinking of theme parameters. Looks like I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Braces must be escaped, i.e. `{{` and `}}` otherwise the xslt-engine will try to eval/compile the expressin in the AVT.

Furthermore, the attribute value must be enclosed in double quotes `"`...`"` and the dict values in single quotes `'`...`'` like the following:

`attributename="{{xyz:'abc'}}"`

this will transform into

`attributename="{xyz:'abc'}"`

**Remember**: when you load the html-template without diazo (i.e. directly from your filesystem) you *must not* escape the braces. Otherwise your plugin eventually will not treat it as a json-string.